# The use of the verb "διερμήνευσεν" in Luke 24:27 is an illustration of the exegetical approach or hermeneutics?

Tags: jesus

In Luke 24:27, when the author of the Gospel used the verb "διερμήνευσεν," is this an illustration of the hermeneutical or exegetical approach that Jesus applied to the Scriptures?

This verb was used in these passages, in addition to Paul's writings:

Legum allegoriarum 3:87  Philo of Alexandria

> … for the name of Isaac, being interpreted, means laughter of soul, and delight, and joy.

Legum allegoriarum 3:87

> …εἰκότως τὸν Ἰσαὰκ  πρὶν γεννηθῆναι ὀνόματός τε καὶ δωρεᾶς μεγάλης ἠξίωσε• γέλως γὰρ ψυχῆς καὶ χαρὰ καὶ εὐφροσύνη διερμηνεύεται οὗτος.

Quod deus sit immutabilis 1:144  Philo of Alexandria

> which is the royal road for those who partake of the faculty of seeing who are called Israel; for the interpretation of the name Edom, is "earthly," and he labors with all earnestness, and by every means in his power, and by threats, to hinder them from this road, and to make it pathless and impracticable for ever.

Quod deus sit immutabilis 1:144

> βουλομένοις γοῦν ταύτην πορεύεσθαι τὴν ὁδὸν βασιλικὴν οὖσαν τοῖς τοῦ ὁρατικοῦ γένους μετέχουσιν, ὅπερ Ἰσραὴλ κέκληται, διαμάχεται ὁ γήινος Ἐδὼμ τοῦτο γὰρ διερμηνευθεὶς ὀνομάζεται μετὰ σπουδῆς καὶ παρασκευῆς τῆς πάσης εἴρξειν ἀπειλῶν τῆς ὁδοῦ καὶ ἀτριβῆ καὶ ἀπόρευτον αὐτὴν κατασκευάσειν εἰσάπαν.

Timaios 3:3

> "It is fitting for one who is competing in the contest to do so with enthusiasm, just as I myself have suffered for the city through which we have passed. For I would willingly listen to an account of the contests in which the city is engaged, those in which she competes against other cities, just as she would be expected to do, having entered into a war, and in waging it, discharging the duties incumbent on education and nurture, both in practical activities and in interpreting words, in relation to each of the cities. So, gentlemen, Critias and Hermocrates, these things..." ) Plato's Works ~ A work nearing completion.

Timaios 3:3

> προσήκειν κατὰ τὴν ἀγωνίαν ἀθλοῦντα• ταὐτὸν καὶ ἐγὼ πέπονθα πρὸς τὴν πόλιν ἣν διήλθομεν. ἡδέως γὰρ ἄν του λόγῳ διεξιόντος ἀκούσαιμ᾽ ἂν ἄθλους οὓς πόλις ἀθλεῖ, τούτους αὐτὴν ἀγωνιζομένην πρὸς πόλεις ἄλλας, πρεπόντως εἴς τε πόλεμον ἀφικομένην καὶ ἐν τῷ πολεμεῖν τὰ προσήκοντα ἀποδιδοῦσαν τῇ παιδείᾳ καὶ τροφῇ κατά τε τὰς ἐν τοῖς ἔργοις πράξεις καὶ κατὰ τὰς ἐν τοῖς λόγοις διερμηνεύσεις πρὸς ἑκάστας τῶν πόλεων. ταῦτ᾽ οὖν, ὦ Κριτία καὶ Ἑρμόκρατες,

2 Maccabees 1:36

> "The people around Nehemiah called this substance 'naphthar,' which is interpreted as purification, but it is commonly called 'naphthai' by many."

2 Maccabees 1:36

> προσηγόρευσαν δὲ οἱ περὶ τὸν Νεεμιαν τοῦτο νεφθαρ ὃ διερμηνεύεται καθαρισμός καλεῖται δὲ παρὰ τοῖς πολλοῖς νεφθαι

Acts 9:36

> In Joppa, there was a disciple named Tabitha, who was also called Dorcas. She was full of good works and acts of charity that she did.

Acts 9:36

> Ἐν Ἰόππῃ δέ τις ἦν μαθήτρια ὀνόματι Ταβιθά, ἣ διερμηνευομένη λέγεται Δορκάς• αὕτη ἦν πλήρης ἔργων ἀγαθῶν καὶ ἐλεημοσυνῶν ὧν ἐποίει. (Acts 9:36 BGT)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a statement and not a question.

Comment: Exegesis does not encompass hermeneutics, as the latter represents a more comprehensive approach to the interpretation of Scriptures. Therefore, asserting that Jesus' interpretation is hermeneutical or exegetical cannot be done absolutely without an analysis of the specific context in question.

Comment: OK.  But what is your question?  Further, since neither of the word Exegesis nor Hermeneutics is used in its modern sense in the NT, I am not sure one can be so precise because the NT does not make such a distinction.

Comment: The concept of exegesis is aligned with the Peshat layer, which focuses on the literal and historical interpretation of Scriptures. The Drash layer, which involves homiletic and ethical interpretations of Scriptures, can be related to hermeneutics. These two approaches to interpretation existed at the time of Jesus.

Comment: "*exegetical approach or hermeneutics*". The question is ambiguous. Are you expecting a "yes/no" or a "former/latter" answer?

Comment: What would be your response to Jesus' interpretation of Isaiah 61:1-2?

Answer (score 2):

The verb διερμηνεύω occurs just six times in the NT, Luke 24:27, Acts 9:36, 1 Cor 12:30, 14:5, 13, 27.  Its meaning is given by BDAG as follows:

> 1. **to translate from one language to another, *translate***, eg, 2 Macc 1:36, Acts 9:36
> 2. **to clarify something so as to make it understandable, *explain, interpret***, eg, ecstatic utterances 1 Cor 12:30, 14:4, 13, 27; the
>    meaning of prophecies Luke 24:27

Jesus' statement in Luke 24:27 is often used by modern exegetes to demonstrate that, for Christian theology, the life and ministry of Jesus Christ is the primary key to understanding all of the sacred Scriptures.  Another similar reference is:

> John 5:39 - You diligently search the Scriptures because you think to
> have eternal life in them, and these are they bearing witness
> concerning Me;

See also John 3:14, 6:32-35, 12:8, 14:6, 1 Cor 10:4, 15:3-7, 2 Cor 1:20, Ps 19:1, Heb 12:2, 3, 1 John 5:11, 12, Rev 1:1, etc.

**APPENDIX - Jesus' Life**

In a spirit of helpfulness, let me offer some comments about the OP's comments.

First, the NT makes no distinction between exegesis and hermeneutics.  Such is quite modern.

Second, many Bible students have observed the close relationship between the life of Jesus and the history of Israel in the OT.  The table below illustrates this.

| OT History | Jesus’ Life |
| --- | --- |
| The progeny of Abraham that created the nation of Israel was made possible by miraculous births of Isaac & Jacob (=Israel) | Jesus’ earthly life became possible by the miraculous birth facilitated by the Holy Spirit |
| Israel is called God’s first-born son, Ex 4:22 | Jesus is Mary’s first-born son, Matt 1:25 |
| Jacob’s family left Canaan for Egypt to escape death by famine | Jesus’ family left Canaan for Egypt to escape death decree by Herod |
| Israel called out of Israel to become God’s people | Jesus; family called out of Egypt to become God’s chosen Messiah |
| Israel passes through the dead sea equivalent to a “baptism” 1 Cor 10:2 | Jesus baptized at the beginning of His ministry |
| After passing through the Red sea, Israel follows the cloud into the desert | After His baptism, Jesus is led by the Spirit into the desert, Matt 4:1 |
| Israel roamed for 40 years in the desert | Jesus spent 40 days fasting in the desert |
| When in the desert, Israel becomes hungry | Jesus fasted in the desert and was hungry |
| Israel healed and saved by faith when they looked at the uplifted bronze serpent | Jesus is the uplifted bronze serpent that saves by faith, John 3:14, 15 |
| Israel fed by “bread from heaven” (Manna) | Jesus is the bread from heaven, John 6 |
| Israel saved by the water from the rock | Jesus is the rock, 1 Cor 10:3, 4 and is the water of life, John 4:10-14, 7:37-39 |
| Moses climbed the mountain to get the to get the law of God | Jesus delivered his sermon of the mount (Matt 5-7) expanding the law |
| The whole ceremonial system represented Jesus as typified by the sacrificial lamb | Jesus is the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world, John 1:29 |
| The Israelites were led by a divine light, the pillar of fire | Jesus is the light of the world, John 8:12, 9:4, 5 |
| Israel began its national history with 12 tribes | Jesus began His kingdom with 12 chosen disciples |
| God used many miracles to establish the Israelite faith | Jesus used many miracles to establish the faith of disciples and Christians |
| King David captured Jerusalem and it became, “The City of David”. | Jesus “captured” Jerusalem at His triumphal entry as king is Israel, John 12:12-15. |
| God establishes a covenant with Israel in Ex 19-23 | Jesus established (or re-established) the (new) covenant |
| Israel was taken captive from the promised land and Jerusalem for their sins | Jesus was taken captive in Jerusalem for the sins of the world and taken outside the city to be crucified |
| The Jews were miraculously preserved and returned to Jerusalem after the Babylonian captivity | Jesus was miraculously resurrected from the dead and returned to Jerusalem to meet the disciples |

To this list, one might add the many OT prophecies of Messiah such as being crucified, being born in Bethlehem, riding on a donkey, etc.

Comment: Did Jesus interpret the Hebrew Scriptures in a straightforward, literal manner, 1.BDAG or did he apply hermeneutical interpretations by considering the context and a broader understanding? 2.BDAG

Comment: @Betho's - I am really struggling to understand the point you are trying to make.  And that is the point - you appear to trying to make a point rather than asking a question!

Comment: The way Jesus interpreted the scriptures was more contextual and symbolic, in line with the approach of Philo of Alexandria, rather than a strictly literal interpretation, as seen in the uses of the word "διερμήνευσεν" mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @Betho's - now you are venturing into a new territory - the extent to which Jesus was or was not influenced by the Greek philosophers of His day.  Jesus certainly understood the OT literally but used it metaphorically, but that is now another question.  He was the second Adam; He was the firstborn out of Egypt; He had a miraculous birth like Isaac; He was the bread from heaven (manna) etc, etc.  If you ask a question like this, I will answer very extensively.

Comment: If Jesus used a metaphorical interpretation, as seen in Matthew 21:16 to Luke 24:27, wasn't he going against the majority of Jews who interpreted messianic passages with a Pshat approach? A notable example was Nicodemus when he addressed the interpretation of "born again."

Comment: @Betho's - I think that is the point - Jesus interpreted all the Bible messianically!

Comment: Is this messianic approach described in Luke 10:21? and an example of it would be described in Acts 8:30-35?

Comment: @Betho's - yes - unless we see Jesus on every page of Scripture, we are missing the point of the bible story as correctly described in the two passages you quote and the many examples in my answer above.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answers. Honestly, if everything is like this in the context of interpretation, the Jews' rejection of Jesus is irreversible. I'll upvote your post again on a whim, but it doesn't completely reflect what I think.